# Ayuda con operación y paréntesis Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, operador, division

int filas = 4;
int columnas = 3;

Tengo que multiplicar filas por columnas, luego dividirlo entre 2, y después restarle 1

Lo tengo así pero me crashea:

```
((filas*columnas) / 2) - 1
```

Lo estoy usando en:

```
    private int[] nuevaBaraja = Arrays.copyOfRange(imagenes, 0, (filas*columnas)/2);
```

Si pongo 5 directamente, funciona

gracias de antemano

Comment: prueba a poner ((filas*columnas/2)-1) , si te sigue crasheando crea una variable que almacene el resultado

Comment: Agrega especifiamente que error obtienes y tu código completo para tener una idea de lo que tratas de lograr.